# Difficulties with combined words as entities in Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm trying to write an intent in Dialogflow that requires the user to fill both a room as well as an object. 
I need to determine if the room is part of a house (check in entity 1) and if the object is made of glass (check in entity 2).

In English, for instance, that would result in '[kitchen] [window]', however I have to do this in Dutch, where a lot of words are combined.
Users should be able to say 'the window of my kitchen is damaged', but in Dutch it is more natural to say 'keukenraam', so: 'my kitchenwindow is damaged.

This one word combines location and object, but I have not been able to use one word to fill two entities.

Does anybody have a good suggestion, because I can't find a proper solution for this problem.

Comment: I doubt that this will work, most (all?) of the default entities come as distinct words, I can't image that they trained their model specifically to support a small number of special cases in a small language. Your best bet is probably to parse the values in your backend.

Comment: It's not just Dutch that has these kind of constructions. Swedish: "köksfönster", German: "Küchenfenster", Finnish: "keittiöikkuna", Norwegian: "kjøkkenvindu".

I'm sure there are more.
The point is: there are more languages that use constructions of combinations.